# What is the difference between getModel() and getDefaultModel() in a Wicket Form?

Tags: java, wicket

Using Apache Wicket 7. Which model should be used in a Form? The default model of the component or the model of the form itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference is that `getModel()` is typesafe, but they both return the same object.

Here's the 7.0.0 implementation of `Form.getModel()` for example:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public final IModel<T> getModel()
{
    return (IModel<T>)getDefaultModel();
}
```

This all goes back to the Wicket 1.3 -> 1.4 transition, which introduced generics into Wicket, and the design decision was to rename the old `getModel()` method to `getDefaultModel()` and redefine `getModel()` in certain components to use the type parameter of that component.

**Long story short: just use `getModel()` wherever possible.**

This is unrelated to the choice of whether you use individual component models, or one big model for the form.

Comment: And in Wicket 8.x this logic is extracted in IGenericComponent mixin/trait, so you can add it easily to your components: https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/e0db538526e222345e07888f742b709f77d988f2/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/IGenericComponent.java

Comment: @martin-g very nice use of it :)